# Selecting an image and knowing what image is selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dom

I have a list of images. when an image is selected the next process is to add features to that same image and edit it.

The problem is i don't know how to identify which particular image is selected. there are tons of images there. is there like a way to store the image temporarily with js or php or something.

like in java if a user selects a particular you can set an if statement like

```
if option==1{
  do this.....
}
```

I want something like that that lets me know which particular image the user has selected. I would attach a picture for more emphasis
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mjvc1.png)
i would like to know how to identify the particular image selected

Comment: You've not really given enough information, but it looks like you could just add a class to the clicked thumbnail, eg. `.active`, and then find that class when needed. Or you could reference the element using `this` in it's own click handler. We need to see some code to be able to help you

Comment: if i do add an active class to the clicked thumbnail how do i retrieve the particular image on that thumbnail. could you be more explicit

Comment: Let me give a scenario. Are you familiar with nike id? if not you can check their website and see what i am about to explain.

Comment: nike id gives you the ability to customize any particular shoe you choose. lets say you choose an air max. you have the ability to change several features on that air max , like the color, design , sole etc

Comment: So the question i asked has to do with how do you retain that particular image on the site while adding new features. like how do you customize that image ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood this is what you need:

```
$('.image').on('click',function(){
  var currentImage=$(this);
};
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){

 $('.image').on('click',function(){
  var currentImage=$(this);
};

    $(".side").fadeOut(500).hide();  
    $(".side1").fadeOut(500).hide();
   
  $(".box1").click(function(){
   
    $(".tab2").fadeIn(500).show();
    $(".tab3").fadeOut(500).hide();
    $(".tab4").fadeOut(500).hide();
    $(".tab5").fadeOut(500).hide();
    $(".side1").fadeOut(500).hide();
   });

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<script>
 function chkimage(img)
 {
  if(img.id=="img1")
  {
   img.height = "200";
  }
  else if(img.id=="img2")
  {
   img.width = "200";
  }
 }
</script>
<body>
<img id="img1" src="Chrysanthemum.jpg" height="100" width="100" onclick="chkimage(this)"/><br/>
<img id="img2" src="Desert.jpg" height="100" width="100" onclick="chkimage(this)"/><br/>
<img id="img3" src="Hydrangeas.jpg" height="100" width="100" onclick="chkimage(this)"/><br/>

</body>
</html>
```